# Laravel Passport: Internal Server Error on POST /token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

When I make a Post Request on Passport's /token like this:

```
{
"form_params" : {
    "grant_type" : "password",
    "client_id" : "2",
    "client_secret" : "my_client_secret",
    "email" : "mymail@mail.com",
    "password" : "passwort1234%",
    "scope" : "*"
}
```

}

I get an internal server error, and despite having the config:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG=daily
APP_LOG_MAX_FILES=90
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

nothing is written in the Log files and the only thing that is returned is the "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." page without any details.

I have no idea why this Error occurs (my own pages, that do not use passport are working).

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Internal server errors are logged in `laravel.log` by default, can you confirm that it is empty after you cause the error?

Comment: It could be a warning, that you accesses closed page without authorization done.

Comment: @NikolaGavric yes, the last entry was a couple of hours ago

Answer (score 1):

The route is `/oauth/token`, most passport routes are preceded by `oauth`.

Routes are defined here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#requesting-tokens

Comment: I changed it to /token, I guess successfully since I get a 404 on /oauth/token

Comment: In that case, is anything coming through your web server's log file indicating the cause of the 500 error?

Comment: nope, strangely nothing is written to the log files

Comment: Ok, add a logging statement at the top of the `report` method in the exception handler class. Nothing should get past that if the problem is originating within the laravel stack.

Comment: ok, Thanks
I got it to work now but still get a 400 due to "unsoported_grant_type"